Automotive Filter
I'm building an automotive parts site and working on a filter to filter the parts by year, make, model, trim and engine.
Each of them are their own tables in the db. Year is related to Make. Make is related to Model. Model is related to Trim and Trim is related to Engine.
I have the data for these tables. Now what I'm trying to figure out is how to have the filter select the appropriate data based on user input.
So for example if a user selects a Year of 2003 with a Make of Nissan, how can I have the Model table only provide Nissan models?
The same goes for Trims after a user selects their Model.
I'm using NextJS(app router) with react-select for the dropdowns and postgres with prisma. If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great!


Join the tables and list your conditions in the where section, or as the join..on conditions. Make sure you normalized these right - it's usually enough to make the year an additional field of a specific other thing, rather than a thing of its own. A foreign key reference to a year is unlikely to be more efficient than the year itself.
